# Can I add a search box in Google Calendar add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace-add-ons

Can I add a search box in Google Calendar add-on ?
This I'll use to search names from list of names present in Google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [TextInput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input) to your card, and attach a [setOnChangeAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input#setOnChangeAction(Action)) to it, so that a function is fired when the text input changes. You can also add a [TextButton](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button), to fire the function when it is clicked.

The triggered function would be passed an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects) with information about the card widgets, including your input text, to be found in field `commonEventObject.formInputs` (see [common event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#common_event_object)). With this information, the function could look for the search results and display these.